# function execution with and without input arguments

Tags: matlab, performance

Just as a Friday Fun, I was wondering which one is faster, `rand` or `rand(1)`. So I wrote the following test:

```
clc,clear,close all
N = 100;
T1 = zeros(1,N);
T2 = zeros(1,N);
for jj=1:N
tic;for ii=1:10000;rand;end;T1(jj)=toc;
tic;for ii=1:10000;rand(1);end;T2(jj)=toc;
end
plot(1:N,T1,'--o',1:N,T2,'--x');
hold on;plot(1:N,mean(T1)*ones(1,N));
hold on;plot(1:N,mean(T2)*ones(1,N));
```

and you can see the results:

[image]

First, I expected `rand(1)` be faster because in the other case, `rand`, there should be some code checking the number of input arguments (`nargin`) and use the default values if there is no argument.  Then I thought there has to be a `switch nargin` and both cases then would consume the same amount of time.
So it doesn't make sense to me why `rand` is faster. Any ideas?

**Extension:**
I have taken the test a little bit further by adding more data:

[image]

I have plotted the test results for `rand` , `rand(1,1)`, `rand(1,2)`, `rand(1,3)`, and `rand(1,100)`. Obviously `rand(1,100)` should take more time to generate a hundred random numbers, but the temporal difference between `rand(1,1)` to `rand(1,100)` is almost the same as the temporal difference between `rand` and `rand(1,1)`.

Comment: As you call the function without parenthesis, Matlab may bypass the `nargin` tests and run it with default values directly. Just an intuition, I don't know the correct answer...

Comment: I think the answer is in the documentation for `rand`.  "X = rand returns a single uniformly distributed random number in the interval (0,1)."  "X = rand(n) returns an n-by-n matrix of random numbers."  Running with `rand(1)` forces Matlab to create a 1 by 1 matrix so it had to first determine that it needed a 1 by 1.  In the other case(`rand`) it doesn't care what the input is, it just creates a single number.

Comment: What if if you `plot(k,time(rand(1,k))`. You would expect the slope to be `time(rand)` and then you could conclude that the extra time is used for matrix-allocation. If it is not linear than you look at the time it takes to allocate a matrix of size `1xk`.

Comment: `timeit` also gives less running time for `rand` than for `rand(1)`